# Save single column datatable to disk fast

Tags: c#, .net, performance, datatable, disk

I've got to save a datatable to disk.  It is just a single column and I've been looping round saving each row, and I've tried adding the rows to a string and then saving that.

```
 For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
 fd.savefile("c:\filename.txt, " " & dt.Rows(i).Item("word"), "append")   'appends to file
 'or
 wordList = wordList & " " & dt.Rows(i).Item("word")  'builds up the word list and..
 Next
 '
 fd.saveFile("c:\filename.txt", "overwrite") 'then saves it to disk.
```

It is very slow.

I've found this:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/250808-storing-datatable-data-hard-disk

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test.bin", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(fs, dt);
fs.Close();
```

That whacks out a serialized version of the data in super quick time. Much faster than my looping processes.  How can I dump the datatable like that, but with no meta-data? It doesn't need to be read back into a datatable.  The serialize method puts  etc tags everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reopen file for each row. Either keep writng to the same stream or simply write all at once with one of `File` helper methods like [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\filename.txt", 
    dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => r.Item("word"));
```

Comment: That's cool.  But it is putting carriage-returns in between each row in the output file.  Can I avoid that somehow?

Comment: @bendecko sure - check out other `File` helpers or write to `StreamWriter` any way you like.

Comment: I see.. I see..  Just getting used to all this.  Thanks!